# Enable function depending on template class variables

Tags: c++, templates

I have a simple matrix class that looks like this:

```
template <int m, int n>
class matrix {
public:
    std::enable_if<std::is_same<matrix, matrix<4,4>>::value, void>
    translate(float x, float y, float z) {
        // Do stuff
    }

private:
    float mat[m * n];
};
```

I expected the `std::enable_if` to make the function only available if I instantiate a `matrix<4,4>`, but it appears that this is wrong.

```
int main() {
    matrix<4, 3> mat3;
    mat3.translate(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    return 0;
}
```

The code above compiles with no errors. What am I doing wrong?

*I know I can simply put a `static_assert(m == 4 && n == 4)` in the function body, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution and want to learn something about templates in the process.*

Comment: You can use `#ifdef` and other C preprocessors to strip out or add functions depending on the template paramter

Comment: @user814628: Um, no you can't. Preprocessing occurs way before template expansion.

Comment: Yea youre right, I was just daydreaming...

Comment: *I want to learn something about templates in the process* is a good goal, but you are aiming for something that is *complex*, there are many things simpler to learn about templates before aiming to do SFINAE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starter, you should be doing:

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<matrix, matrix<4,4>>::value, void>::type
```

Instead of just:

```
std::enable_if<std::is_same<matrix, matrix<4,4>>::value, void>
```

But this would still not work, because the condition would be evaluated when the class template is instantiated, thus yielding an error even if you never call `translate()`.

If you can use C++11, you could do the following:

```
template<typename T = matrix>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T, matrix<4,4>>::value>
    ::type
translate(float x, float y, float z) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=78698238cb30e063253937ecd3d9379f-4c7a93babd200e4d38472bfd414f71ce). Notice, how the compilation error is triggered by the call to `translate()`, and not by the mere instantiation of `matrix<4,3>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use && and == in the argument to enable_if. Also, you forgot the ::type, which is the member that only exists when the condition is true (and so does the enabling). This also requires adding a typename. Here is the code that works:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int m, int n>
class matrix {
public:
    typename std::enable_if<m == 4 && n == 4, void>::type
    translate(float x, float y, float z) {
       // Do stuff
    }

private:
    float mat[m * n];
};

int main() {
    // Compile fine
    matrix<4, 4> mat4;
    mat4.translate(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Compile error
    matrix<4, 3> mat3;
    mat3.translate(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But this will cause a compilation error when you instantiate the class though, not when you invoke `translate()`

Comment: That won't work either... SFINAE only applies to the template/template function. In this case you are attempting SFINAE on a non-template function that is itself part of a template. You need to make that function a template itself.